# Empty result try find element in array Mongodb v4 (broke compatibility)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

why second command return empty result? Its work in mongodb 3 version after update to 4 version broking...

// Command #1:

```
 db.c.find({ 
     AlbumId: HexData(3, "ca79977db39b1640a45e13dc5a06cb48"),
 })
```

// Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e30aaadfc253f6d211aefb1"), "AlbumId" : BinData(3,"ynmXfbObFkCkXhPcWgbLSA=="),  "Items" : [ ] }
```

// Command #2:

```
db.c.find({ 
    AlbumId: HexData(3, "ca79977db39b1640a45e13dc5a06cb48"),
    Items: { "$elemMatch" : { "field" : { "$ne" : HexData(3, "ad326a5404856c4e9fb4aafa6f0430e6") }}} 
})
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you are searching for "field" instead of value. Is "field" an actual fieldname?

Comment: 1) yes  "field" an actual fieldname  and  i try change 'field' to filed 'AlbumName'